# Change the permissions and ownership of tty port in android programmatically

Tags: android, adb

I need to change the permission of /dev/tty* file as I am writing data on that port. I am able to change the permission from the windows command prompt by entering the adb shell as root.

But when I reboot the device, the permissions are not persisted. Instead, they are set to default values.

So, every time I need to run my app after reboot, I need to change the permissions.

I tried to run the adb commands from the app by using `Runtime.exec()` method but that does not change anything as the app does not have permission to change the file ownership permissions.

This is how I executed the command from app ( tested it in emulator in this case) :

```
Process process =   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("chown root:root /dev/ttyS0 \n");
os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0 \n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
process.waitFor();
```

When the "su" command gets executed, it gives the error `su: uid 10044 not allowed to su`

Because of that, on executing chown or chmod gives error `Unable to chmod Operation Not permitted`

So, how do I change permissions and ownership of that file ?

Any help is highly appreciated !

Thanks !!

Comment: Emulator or device? If device then rooted or not? And what do you mean by saying "run `adb root` programmatically from the `android app`"?

Comment: it is in the device.. In order to change the permission of /dev/tty* file through command prompt, I need to enter adb shell after giving adb root command ie., adb has to run as root.. if not, it does not let me change the permission

Comment: and I am able to change the permissions through command prompt. But I want to do the similar process through code.

Comment: It's a rooted phone or not? Do you want to run `adb` command from your app?

Comment: yes. it is a rooted phone.. and yes I want to run the `adb root` command from my app

Comment: How do you plan to run adb command? AFAIK `adb` is a PC command (windows/linux/mac). It's the main program that connect the PC & Device/emulator.

Comment: I have updated the question.. can you please check it

Answer (score 1):

The default (from the [Google AOSP source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.cpp)) `su` binary checks `UID` it is being run with. Only `root` and `shell` users are allowed to run `su`. You won't be able to run `su` from your application unless you install the patched `su` binary which does not check the `UID`.

All what `adb root` command does is executing the following commands on the device:

```
setprop service.adb.root 1
stop adbd
start adbd
```

But I am positive that you are asking a wrong question here. There is no reason why `su` command would not work for your purpose.

The command you should be executing to change the tty device permissions is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su 0 chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0");
```

Also in android the `.` is used as a delimiter between user and group fields in the `chown` command instead of the `:`. The proper command would be:

```
su 0 chown root.root /dev/ttyS0
```

Another common mistake is trying to use standard Linux `su` options like `-c`. AOSP version of `su` is much simpler:

```
usage: su [UID[,GID[,GID2]...]] [COMMAND [ARG...]]

        Switch to WHO (default 'root') and run the given command (default sh).
        where WHO is a comma-separated list of user, group,
        and supplementary groups in that order.
```