# How to change permission of internal folder/file in android?

Tags: android, file-permissions, adb

I wanted to get database file from the emulator. So, I tried to change the permission of package folder using `adb shell`. When I use the below command:

```
adb shell su -c chmod 777 /data/data/com.mypackage.test
```

It always returns:

```
Chmod: need 2 arguments
```

I have changed permission some days ago using above command. But recently I'm always getting the above warning. I have searched a lot and found large information regarding using above command but no one mentioned about this warning issue.

Comment: not sure that it would work, but try to use quotes for the whole command that you want to execute, like `adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/com.mypackage.test"`

Comment: Issue remain exists even after adding the quotes.

Comment: `adb shell "su 0 'chmod 777 /data/data/com.mypackage.test'"`

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758169/1778421

Comment: I have same error please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628647/android-room-database-file-is-invalid-file-format-in-db-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this issue instead of running `adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data"`, I run the `adb shell` first and then the following command : `su -c "chmod 777 /data"`.

[image]

Comment: I have a same problem please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628647/android-room-database-file-is-invalid-file-format-in-db-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this issue ： `adb shell su -c 'chmod 777 /data/data/com.mypackage.test'`