# Android Room database file is invalid file format in DB browser

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I am going to `data/data/myPackage` in emulator and download these three files about my apps database :

[image]

But when i import it to DB browser i faced with this error :

[image]

I think the problem is about permissions`(-rw------)` because when i import other database that has this `(-rw-rw----)`,DB browser can open it.

**Then how can i change permission or open my room database in DB browser?**

This is my room config :

```
@Database(entities = {Authentication.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class InsensitiveDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static InsensitiveDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract AuthenticationDao authenticationDao();

    public static InsensitiveDatabase getInsensitiveDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            Editable editable = new SpannableStringBuilder("1234");
            SafeHelperFactory factory = SafeHelperFactory.fromUser(editable);
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, InsensitiveDatabase.class, "insensitive.db")
                    .openHelperFactory(factory)
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: which file are you opening in SqliteBrowser ?

Comment: @m3g4tr0n , the first one , but i tried all of them

Comment: Can you upload your file somewhere from where I could download

Comment: I think its about permission , what do you think?

Comment: I don't think so, Sqlite Browser clearly says Invalid File Format

Comment: @m3g4tr0n , [link](https://filebin.net/bj9wjvck01hbtbl5)

Comment: Just tried, I am getting a different error : Could Not Open Database File, Reason file is not a Database

Comment: Add Some Data to tables then try exporting once again

Comment: @m3g4tr0n , you import it in DB browser or other one?

Comment: Try adding ```exportSchema``` in ```@Database(entities = {Authentication.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false) ```

Comment: Definitely not an SQLite Database first 16 bytes should be **SQLite format 3\000** instead the first bytes are ãOÀDó7QXªäÒŽ×ðôdwÔ¢. I'd suggest try copying the 3 files again.

Comment: @MikeT: This is a SQLCipher for Android database; I do not know if they share the same byte header.

Comment: @CommonsWare then it would need to be opened with the key as I believe that decrypts the entire file.

Comment: "how can i change permission" -- you need to be copying the files down to your development machine before attempting to use them in some external tool. "open my room database in DB browser?" -- I have no idea if that tool supports SQLCipher databases.

Comment: @CommonsWare I believe you can IF you have a version of DB Browser with SQliteCipher.

Comment: Thanks for your answering every body , @CommonsWare , you mean is that DB browser does not support SQLCipher database?

Comment: at [Encrypted Databases](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Encrypted-Databases) it says *DB Browser for SQLite can be downloaded with SQLCipher support on Mac OSX and Windows, or if you compile it yourself you can get support on Linux.* But then says *You can only encrypt an existing database, so if you want a new encrypted database you first need to create a new database file and then encrypt it.* So wondering if it's a self contained so can't open a db encrypted elsewhere.

Comment: "you mean is that DB browser does not support SQLCipher database?" -- as I wrote, I have no idea if that tool supports SQLCipher databases.

Comment: Most likely sqlite browser doesn't work properly, try other ones

Comment: @kosas , i use  Stetho [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138442/browse-sqlite-database-from-android-studio)  library that faceboook release it and sqliteviewer but does not show anything again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i found The DB browser that developed in Linux cant open my encrypted room database because i open it in MAC OS.

**You can see more detail in [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom/issues/58) issue that i open it,i hope that this is useful for your problem**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SQLCipher** in Room DB then it will not show in App Inspection->Database Inspector

Remove this below line and check-

.openHelperFactory(factory) //will not show  in App Inspection ->Database inspection